# Can you please provide some topic ideas related to AI to be used in a project?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, neural-network, genetic-algorithm

I need topic ideas related to AI on which I will base my thesis. I am mostly interested in Genetic Algorithm and Neural Networks techniques. I already got the some ideas, but non of them seems to hit me!

Any help will be really appreciated!! :)

Comment: Should prooooobably be community wiki.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Russ Greiner](http://www.cs.ualberta.ca/~greiner/C-466/suggested-project.html) has a great list of project topics for his machine learning course, so that's a great place to start.

Both GAs and ANNs are learners/classifiers. So I ask you the question, what is an interesting "thing" to learn? Maybe it's:

1. Detecting cancer
2. Predicting the outcome between two sports teams
3. Filtering spam
4. Detecting faces
5. Reading text (OCR)
6. Playing a game

The sky is the limit, really!

Answer (score 0):

I think your thesis should involve a project of a high-carnage shooting game in the style of [Smash TV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smash_TV) or [Crimsonland](http://www.crimsonland.com/) that uses the player as the fitness function for a GA engine: generating behavioral control code for the enemies and evaluating fitness by how long the controlled entity survives and/or how much damage it does to the player.

That'd be fun.

Answer (score 0):

What's a problem that you are passionate about? If you pick something that you love and are interested in you will undoubtedly do a better job and learn more. I love finance but it is not for everyone. GA's are best at optimization problems so maybe portfolio optimization using GAs and ANNs.

Maybe predict which blog posts someone will like. I have always wanted to do that but I have not gotten around to it?