# looking for a good project to work on as my graduation project in the university that involves Ai / Machine Learning, please help me

Tags: artificial-intelligence, machine-learning

I need help to chose a project to work on for my master graduation, The project must involve Ai / Machine learning or Business intelegence.. but if there is any other suggestion out of these topics it is Ok, please help me.

Answer (score 2):

One of the most rapid growing areas in AI today is Computer Vision. There are many practical needs where the results of your Master Thesis can be helpful. You can try research something like Emotion Detection, Eye-Tracking, etc.

An appropriate work for a MS in CS in any good University can highlight the current status of research on this field, compare different approaches and algorithms. As a practical part, it makes also a lot of fun when your program recognizes your mood properly :)

Comment: Thank you,
yes. I get that but I am looking for suggestions for a specific project not general topics

Answer (score 2):

**Netflix**

If you want to work more on non trivial datasets (not google size, but not trivial either and with real application), with an objective measure of success, why not working on the [netflix challenge](http://www.netflixprize.com) (the first one) ?  You can get all the data for free, you have many papers on it, as well as pretty good way to compare your results vs other peoples (since everyone used exactly the same dataset, and it was not so easy to "cheat", contrary to what happens quite often in the academic literature). While not trivial in size, you can work on it with only one computer (assuming it is recent enough), and depending on the type of algorithms you are using, you can implement them in a language which is not C/C++, at least for prototyping (for example, I could get decent results doing things entirely in python).

Bonus point, it passes the "family" test: easy to tell your parents what you are working on, which is always a pain in my experience :)

**Music-related tasks**

A bit more original: something that is both cool, not trivial but not too complicated in data handling is anything around music, like music genre recognition (classical / electronic / jazz / etc...). You would need to know about signal processing as well, though - I would not advise it if you cannot get easy access to professors who know about the topic.

Answer (score 2):

I can use the same [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343710/can-you-please-provide-some-topic-ideas-related-to-ai-to-be-used-in-a-project/1343750#1343750) I used on a previous, similar question:

[Russ Greiner](http://www.cs.ualberta.ca/~greiner/C-466/suggested-project.html) has a great list of project topics for his machine learning course, so that's a great place to start.

Both GAs and ANNs are learners/classifiers. So I ask you the question, what is an interesting "thing" to learn? Maybe it's:

1. Detecting cancer
2. Predicting the outcome between two sports teams
3. Filtering spam
4. Detecting faces
5. Reading text (OCR)
6. Playing a game

The sky is the limit, really!

Answer (score 1):

Since it has a business tie in - given some input set determine probable business fraud from the input (something the SEC seems challenged in doing).  We now have several examples (Madoff and others).  Or a system to estimate investment risk (there are lots of such systems apparently but were any accurate in the case of Lehman for example).

A starting point might be the Chen book [Genetic Algorithms and Genetic Programming in Computational Finance](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0792376013).

Here's an AAAI writeup of an award to the National Association of Securities Dealers for a system that[monitors NASDAQ insider trading](http://www.aaai.org/Pressroom/Releases/release-03-0917.php).

Answer (score 0):

Many great answers posted already, but I wanted to add my 2 cents.There is one hot topic in which big companies all around are investing lots of resources into, and is still a very challenging topic with lots of potential: Automated detection of fake news.

This is even more relevant nowadays where most of us are connecting though social media and there's a huge crisis looming over.

Fake news, content removal, source reliability... The problem is huge and very exciting. It is as I said challenging as it can be seen from many perspectives (from analising images to detect fakes using adversarial netwotks to detecting fake written news based on text content (NLP) or using graph theory to find sources) and the possbilities for a research proyect are endless.

I suggest you read some general articles (e.g [this](https://www.technologyreview.com/2020/05/12/1001633/ai-is-still-largely-baffled-by-covid-misinformation/) or [this](https://www.technologyreview.com/2020/01/08/130983/were-fighting-fake-news-ai-bots-by-using-more-ai-thats-a-mistake/)) or have a look at research articles from the last couple of years (a quick google seach will throw you a lot of related stuff).

I wish I had the opportunity of starting over a project based on this topic. I think it's going to be of the upmost relevance in the next few years.